# Sort results in Azure Maps Search

Tags: azure, rest, api, azure-maps

i'm using AzureMaps Search and i'm trying to retrieve all POI(point of interest) in a location, but i can't find in any documentation how to sort, for example by distance my results

Someone has same problem?

https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/poi/json?subscription-key=key&api-version=1.0&query=restaurant&lat=45&lon=9

Comment: Which distance would you like to sort by, straight-line distance which most services do, but can be highly inaccurate, or based on driving distance?

Comment: It's enough straight line distance, driving distance should be awsome

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the current [Search POI API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchpoi) provides sorting as part of the API itself. So, you'll have to do that in-memory afterwards. The results are sorted by "score"(relevancy) by default.

Comment: So if i have 1000 results, i have to read all and Than sort at runtime.. not the best

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to order by results with POI,I guess what you're looking for here. As per the best practices, you could use [`nearby-search`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-best-practices-for-search#nearby-search)

```
https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/json?subscription-key={subscription-key}&api-version=1&query=400%20Broad%20Street%2C%20Seattle%2C%20WA&countrySet=US
```

Comment: Yes but with nearby,  i can't query for category, so i have the same problem,  read all results, and test if is the right category

Comment: In that case use limit and radius with POI "https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/poi/category/json?api-version=1.0&query={{2}}&lat={{0}}&lon={{1}}&radius={{3}}&limit={{4}}";

Comment: with category it work, but if i use, /search/poi, for search by name not

Comment: it really depends on what you need, maybe you need to tweak a bit with the combinations

Comment: I need to allow user for search for restaurant/cafe by name, and should search all over the world, or search by category 'restaurant' nearby, and i need that all the results are ordered by distance

Comment: I'm using here map now, and all the results are sorted by distance

Answer (score 1):

If you would like straight line distances you can loop through the results can calculate the distances using the [haversine formula](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). If using the Azure Maps Web SDK, you can use the [atlas.math.getDistanceTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.math?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest#functions) function instead. Once you calculate a distance to each point, then you can sort accordingly.

If you want to get the driving distance to each point there are two approaches you can take;

1. Use the [Route Matrix API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/route/postroutematrixpreview). This is fairly easy to use, would be less error prone than the second option below and the response is easy enough to work with. Only negative with this approach is that you will need to S1 pricing tier to access this service and each cell would generate a transaction which can get expensive fast.
2. Use the [Routing Directions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/route/getroutedirections) with a large number of waypoints that go from your origin to each destination and back (A->B->A->C....). This will be a bit more work to understand the results and if any leg of the route is unrouteable for any reason, the whole route calculation would fail. However, this would be significantly cheaper than option one as you can use S0 pricing tier which has free limits and this would only generate 1 transaction in most cases (if you have a large number of locations then you might need to break them up and spread across a few calls). Because this would calculate the route from the origin to each destination and back, you twice as many calculations are made than you need which could make this slower than approach 1. When parsing the response you would look at the odd indexed route legs as those would go from the origin to each destination. In some scenarios it might be desirable to know the travel time from the destinations to the origin (i.e. how long would it take all employees to get to work), in which case the even numbered legs is what you would want to use.

Again, once you have the distance, or better yet, travel time, you can then sort the results accordingly.

Comment: Ok, but this is exactly what i don't want, i can't loop over thousands results and make another call. It took too time...

Comment: Actually, the POI search service already returns a straight line distance value. You could simply sort based on that. Sorting thousands of results is actually pretty fast. That said, the service doesn't return thousands of results, there is a maximum of 100 results returned.